# List from database ms server

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to populate a gridView with information of a database,the information is generated correctly,but i'm getting this error:

```
[System.FormatException] = {"Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."}
```

The code below,why i'm getting this error if the list is correct?

```
public List<StatusClicComplete> SelectStatusClicDB(Clic objClic , out Status returnStatus)
        {


            const string strStoredProcedure = "spSearchClicStatusTESTE";

            List<StatusClicComplete> complete = new List<StatusClicComplete>();

            try
            {


                Database database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(DATABASESETTINGS.CLICDB);
                using (DbCommand dbCommand = database.GetStoredProcCommand(strStoredProcedure))
                {
                    database.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@iClic", DbType.Int32, objClic.ID);

                    using (IDataReader dataReader = database.ExecuteReader(dbCommand))
                    {
                        while (dataReader.Read())
                        {
                            StatusClicComplete statusClicComplete =  new StatusClicComplete();
                            statusClicComplete.iClic = objClic.ID;
                            statusClicComplete.iStatus = (int)dataReader["iStatus"];

                            statusClicComplete.dtDateCreated = (DateTime)dataReader["dtDateCreated"];
                            statusClicComplete.iEDV = (int)dataReader["iEDV"];
                            statusClicComplete.sComments = dataReader["sComments"].ToString();
                            complete.Add(statusClicComplete);
                        }
                        dataReader.Close();

                        returnStatus = StatusBuilder.BuildStatus("Success", string.Format("{0} - {1}", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name), true);

                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {

                returnStatus = StatusBuilder.BuildStatus("Error", string.Format("{0} - {1}", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, exception.Message), false);

            }
            //TODO NAV8CA   - Escrever tratativa de objeto nulo
            return complete;

}
```

Comment: Which line in the code is the error occurring on?

Comment: Have you verified that the `iStatus`, `dtDateCreated`, `iEDV`, and `sComments` columns are actually available in the records available to the data reader? It almost seems as though one of those columns is missing, which would lead to a failure in the `dataReader["column"]` expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line looks wrong to me..

```
returnStatus = StatusBuilder.BuildStatus("Success", string.Format("{0} - {1}", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name), true);
```

You're using a `string.Format` with 2 formatting placeholders, but only passing in one item.

Comment: This is indeed a problem, but I'm not sure that it's the problem with the originally specified error. I think that `string.Format()` is robust enough to deal with situations such as this. The specified error reads like an array indexing issue to me.

Comment: I thought that as well @JeffFerguson. What made me suspect the `string.Format()` was the `[System.FormatException] ` part of the error message. But you're right, could be an indexing issue on the dataReader array too.

Comment: Upon further review ... perhaps you're right. The `IDataRecord` indexer throws an exception of type `IndexOutOfRangeException` when no column with the specified name was found, according to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1a8yx17k(v=vs.100).aspx). The original poster is catching a `FormatException` and not an `IndexOutOfRangeException`  exception.

Comment: I found more evidence for your answer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx), so I am sending an upvote your way. The `string.Format()` method will throw a `FormatException` if, and I quote from the documentation, _The index of a format item is less than zero, or greater than or equal to the number of arguments in the arguments list._

Comment: Thx,it was the placeholders indeed.